# Excel Auto Save With Updated "Date Modified"

Tags: excel

I am trying to get Excel to auto save in a way that updates the "Date Modified".

I tried using:

File>Options>Save>"Save AutoRecover information every XX minutes"

But this doesn't change the modified date.

Is there a way to get Excel to auto save that also updates the "Date Modified"?

I am using Office 365: Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.7329.1045) 32-bit

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to change the modified date is to save the file. If you want to force saving file you need to implement a timer to do this. It is not the best solution to work with timer, but the only one i can imagine at the moment.
Here is my proposed code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Wakeup = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    Application.OnTime Wakeup, "Tabelle1.PeriodicTask"
End Sub

Public Sub PeriodicTask()
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Wakeup = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    Application.OnTime Wakeup, "Tabelle1.PeriodicTask"
End Sub
```

Copy this into your file and it will be saved each 5 minutes. If you want an other time interval change it in the code.